# Magnific Popup not loading on specific parts of page

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup, magnific-popup

I'm trying call a popup with a link and using Magnific Popup to achieve the same. The code is working properly on test conditions but during integration to main project, it refuses to open.

The code I'm using to call the popup is as follows

```
<a class="popup-modal" href="#callflow">Open Open Popup</a>
```

**And it works perfectly while running standalone.** I am trying to integrate this with the following dynamic code fragment.

```
<td id="data_column_new" class="xcol" style="background-color:<?=$colour;?>" width=50>
<a href="javascript:popup('popUpDiv','<?=$dataset['orderid'];?>','<?=$followdate;?>',
'<?=$dataset['sales_status'];?>','<?=$dataset['sremark'];?>','<?=$id;?>','<?=$closuredate;?>');">
<img src="<?=$generalVars['IMAGE_ROOT']?>editIcon.gif" id="<?=$id;?>" />
</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;

<a class="popup-modal" href="#callflow">Open Popup</a>

&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:showSalesTransHistory('<?=base64_encode($dataset['orderid']);?>')" 
style="color:#003399;text-decoration:none">
<?=$dataset['sales_status'];?>
</a>
```

But while clicking link this time, it gives nothing but a change in url(adding #callflow as per the link). **Strangely, the same link works in other parts of program.** What prevents my popup from loading on this specific fragment?

Comment: Are there any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: No. Console is clean.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set Z-index to the maximum for your Magnific Popup.
As far as css is concerned it should be z-index issue.
And also please check if your Background is transparent.
Happy Coding :)